# Calling next class not opening a new window in java using swing

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to open a new screen from the existing screen using the below code,

```
CheckABunch frame = new CheckABunch();
frame.setVisible(true);
```

But the window is not opening. Whenever i try to execute second class its open the window. But when i'm trying to provide inter link to the next screen its not opening the screen. My first class extends JFrame and my next class extends JPanel.

My First class is below,

```
public class ConfigureSystemPage extends JFrame{
    JTextField text;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        new ConfigureSystemPage();
    }

    public ConfigureSystemPage(){
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Configure System");
        f.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
        JLabel lab = new JLabel("System:");
        final JRadioButton Male,Female;
        ButtonGroup radioGroup=new ButtonGroup();
        Male=new JRadioButton("CPU");
        radioGroup.add(Male);
        Female=new JRadioButton("Monitor");
        radioGroup.add(Female);
        Female.setSelected(true);
        JButton cancelbutton=new JButton("Cancel");
        JButton button=new JButton("Next");
        lab.setBounds(50,20,70,20);
        Male.setBounds(110,20,100,20);
        Female.setBounds(210,20,150,20);
        button.setBounds(50,50,80,15);
        cancelbutton.setBounds(50,50,80,15);
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                if((Male.isSelected()==false)&&(Female.isSelected()==false)){
                    System.out.println("if part ");
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Please select system settings");
                }else {
                    System.out.println("else part ");
                    CheckABunch frame = new CheckABunch();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                }
            }
        });
        f.add(lab);
        f.add(Male);
        f.add(Female);
        f.add(button);

        f.setSize(1000,700);
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

And i'm using the below class as second class,

```
public class CheckABunch extends JPanel {

    private static final int CHECK_COL = 1;
    private static final Object[][] DATA = {
            {"One", Boolean.TRUE}, {"Two", Boolean.FALSE},
            {"Three", Boolean.TRUE}, {"Four", Boolean.FALSE},
            {"Five", Boolean.TRUE}, {"Six", Boolean.FALSE},
            {"Seven", Boolean.TRUE}, {"Eight", Boolean.FALSE},
            {"Nine", Boolean.TRUE}, {"Ten", Boolean.FALSE}, {"One", Boolean.TRUE}, {"Two", Boolean.FALSE},
            {"Three", Boolean.TRUE}, {"Four", Boolean.FALSE},
            {"Five", Boolean.TRUE}, {"Six", Boolean.FALSE},
            {"Seven", Boolean.TRUE}, {"Eight", Boolean.FALSE},
            {"Nine", Boolean.TRUE}, {"Ten", Boolean.FALSE}};
    private static final String[] COLUMNS = {"Number", "CheckBox"};
    private DataModel dataModel = new DataModel(DATA, COLUMNS);
    private JTable table = new JTable(dataModel);
    private DefaultListSelectionModel selectionModel;

    public CheckABunch() {
        super(new BorderLayout());
        this.add(new JScrollPane(table));
        this.add(new ControlPanel(), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(250, 175));
        selectionModel = (DefaultListSelectionModel) table.getSelectionModel();
    }

    private class DataModel extends DefaultTableModel {

        public DataModel(Object[][] data, Object[] columnNames) {
            super(data, columnNames);
        }

        @Override
        public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
            if (columnIndex == CHECK_COL) {
                return getValueAt(0, CHECK_COL).getClass();
            }
            return super.getColumnClass(columnIndex);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
            return column == CHECK_COL;
        }
    }

    private class ControlPanel extends JPanel {

        public ControlPanel() {
            this.add(new JLabel("Selection:"));
            this.add(new JButton(new SelectionAction("Clear", false)));
            this.add(new JButton(new SelectionAction("Finish", true)));
        }
    }

    private class SelectionAction extends AbstractAction {

        boolean value;
        String name;

        public SelectionAction(String name, boolean value) {
            super(name);
            this.name = name;
            this.value = value;
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if(name.equalsIgnoreCase("Finish")) {

            }else {
                for (int i = 0; i < dataModel.getRowCount(); i++) {
                    //                if (selectionModel.isSelectedIndex(i)) {
                    System.out.println("actionPerformed value : " + value+" "+i+" "+CHECK_COL+" "+name);
                    dataModel.setValueAt(value, i, CHECK_COL);
                    //                }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static void createAndShowUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Configure Customer");
        frame.add(new CheckABunch());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setSize(1000,700);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                createAndShowUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Could you please suggest me any idea to do this? thanks in advance.

Comment: Post a complete minimal example reproducing the problem.

Comment: @JBNizet I have posted the two class. Please check it

Comment: CheckABunch is not a JFrame. It's a JPanel. You can't just make a JPanel visible and hope it opens in a new window. Only top-level containers such as JFrame, JWindow and JDialog can be made visible like that. A JPanel is supposed to be added to a top-level container. You probably want a JDialog here.

Comment: `Whenever i try to execute second class its open the window.`What does that mean? Where do you call it, so a window opens? What do you mean with execute second? Creating an object of that type?

Comment: @ThomasBöhm I'm mean, i'm executing that class separately. That time its opening new window

Comment: @JBNizet I'm new to this java app development. can u pls post any reference or sample code snippet to do this?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html

Answer (score -1):

I have did this by add JPanel with my top level container like JB Nizet suggestion. And my code is below,

```
 public class ConfigureSystemPage extends JFrame{

        JTextField text;
        private static final int CHECK_COL = 1;
        private static final Object[][] DATA = {
                {"One", Boolean.TRUE}, {"Two", Boolean.FALSE},
                {"Three", Boolean.TRUE}, {"Four", Boolean.FALSE},
                {"Five", Boolean.TRUE}, {"Six", Boolean.FALSE},
                {"Seven", Boolean.TRUE}, {"Eight", Boolean.FALSE},
                {"Nine", Boolean.TRUE}, {"Ten", Boolean.FALSE}, {"One", Boolean.TRUE}, {"Two", Boolean.FALSE},
                {"Three", Boolean.TRUE}, {"Four", Boolean.FALSE},
                {"Five", Boolean.TRUE}, {"Six", Boolean.FALSE},
                {"Seven", Boolean.TRUE}, {"Eight", Boolean.FALSE},
                {"Nine", Boolean.TRUE}, {"Ten", Boolean.FALSE}};
        private static final String[] COLUMNS = {"Number", "CheckBox"};
        private DataModel dataModel = new DataModel(DATA, COLUMNS);
        private JTable table = new JTable(dataModel);
        private DefaultListSelectionModel selectionModel;

        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
            new ConfigureSystemPage();
        }

        public ConfigureSystemPage(){
            JFrame f = new JFrame("Configure System");
            f.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
            JLabel lab = new JLabel("System:");
            final JRadioButton Male,Female;
            ButtonGroup radioGroup=new ButtonGroup();
            Male=new JRadioButton("Expeditors");
            radioGroup.add(Male);
            Female=new JRadioButton("Non Expeditors");
            radioGroup.add(Female);
            Female.setSelected(true);
            JButton cancelbutton=new JButton("Cancel");
            JButton button=new JButton("Next");
            lab.setBounds(50,20,70,20);
            Male.setBounds(110,20,100,20);
            Female.setBounds(210,20,150,20);
            button.setBounds(50,50,80,15);
            cancelbutton.setBounds(50,50,80,15);
            button.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                    if((Male.isSelected()==false)&&(Female.isSelected()==false)){
                        System.out.println("if part ");
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Please select system settings");
                    }else {
                        System.out.println("else part ");
                        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                try {
                                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                                    ex.printStackTrace();
                                }

                                JFrame frame = new JFrame("EI Scanning");
                                //                          frame.setExtendedState(java.awt.Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
                                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                                JPanel content = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
                                //                content.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
                                content.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(20, 20, 20, 20));
                                frame.setContentPane(content);
                                frame.add(new CustomerConfigurationPane());
                                frame.pack();
                                frame.setSize(1000,700);
                                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                                frame.setVisible(true);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            });
            f.add(lab);
            f.add(Male);
            f.add(Female);
            f.add(button);

            f.setSize(1000,700);
            f.setVisible(true);
            f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        }

        public class CustomerConfigurationPane extends JPanel {

            public CustomerConfigurationPane() {
                super(new BorderLayout());
                this.add(new JScrollPane(table));
                this.add(new ControlPanel(), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
                table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(250, 175));
                selectionModel = (DefaultListSelectionModel) table.getSelectionModel();
            }

        }

        private class DataModel extends DefaultTableModel {

            public DataModel(Object[][] data, Object[] columnNames) {
                super(data, columnNames);
            }

            @Override
            public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
                if (columnIndex == CHECK_COL) {
                    return getValueAt(0, CHECK_COL).getClass();
                }
                return super.getColumnClass(columnIndex);
            }

            @Override
            public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
                return column == CHECK_COL;
            }
        }

        private class ControlPanel extends JPanel {

            public ControlPanel() {
                this.add(new JLabel("Selection:"));
                this.add(new JButton(new SelectionAction("Clear", false)));
                this.add(new JButton(new SelectionAction("Finish", true)));
            }
        }

        private class SelectionAction extends AbstractAction {

            boolean value;
            String name;

            public SelectionAction(String name, boolean value) {
                super(name);
                this.name = name;
                this.value = value;
            }

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if(name.equalsIgnoreCase("Finish")) {

                }else {
                    for (int i = 0; i < dataModel.getRowCount(); i++) {
                        //                if (selectionModel.isSelectedIndex(i)) {
                        System.out.println("actionPerformed value : " + value+" "+i+" "+CHECK_COL+" "+name);
                        dataModel.setValueAt(value, i, CHECK_COL);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        }
```

Thank u JB Nizet. Happy Coding...